# Trying To Do A Simple Add Item To FIXTURE

Tags: ember.js

**I have a simple fixture:**

```
App.User.FIXTURES = [
    { userid: 1, name: 'George', email: 'george@gmail.com', bio: 'Lorem Ipsum', created: 'Jan 5, 2015' },
    { userid: 2, name: 'Tom', email: 'tom@hotmail.com', bio: 'Lorem Ipsum 2', created: 'Jan 15, 2015' },
    { userid: 3, name: 'Mary', email: 'mary@aol.com', bio: 'Lorem Ipsum 3', created: 'Jan 25, 2015' }
];
```

**And I have a simple submit: (snippet)**

```
App.AddController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        save: function () {
            App.User.createRecord({ id: 4, userid: 4, name: 'Created person', email: 'sdh', bio: 'my bio', created: '6543456' });
```

I THINK this is right as I'm not getting an error on createRecord anymore, but now I'm getting an error, any ideas? One more step I'm missing just to shove something into a fixture?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    if (!wasApplied) {
      Class.proto(); // prepare prototype...
    }
    o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);
    o_defineProperty(this, '_super', undefinedDescriptor);
```

Comment: What did you change to cause the error?  You need to call save on the new record to actually save it back to the store.  `var user = App.User.createRecord({ id: 4, userid: 4, name: 'Created person', email: 'sdh', bio: 'my bio', created: '6543456' }); user.save();`  See this part of the guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/creating-a-new-model/

Comment: Thanks Sarus. Completely new to this and trying to get a quick grasp of this ASAP.

Your thing worked, but I get an error I guess on the save?

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///G:/users. The request was redirected to 'file:///G:/users/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Comment: Just trying to put the new item back into the store so it updates my list in the UI. Nothing JSON or fancy, just a local thing.

Comment: If you are purely local don't call save, it isn't necessary for injecting it into the store.

Comment: This is an old way of using ember data, which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Kingpin2k is correct in that calling createRecord on the UserModel itself is an older way of using Ember Data.  If you're using the latest version you should call `createRecord` from the store object.

Here's what it should look like:

```
App.AddController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        save: function () {
            //Create a new user
            var user = this.store.createRecord('user',{ 
                 id: 4, 
                 userid: 4, 
                 name: 'Created person', 
                 email: 'sdh', 
                 bio: 'my bio', 
                 created: '6543456' 
            });
            // Saves the new model, but not needed if you're just using FIXTURES
            // Making the call shouldn't throw any errors though and is used in the Guide
            user.save();
            // Now you can find your record in the store
            this.store.find('user', 4).then(function(user){
                console.info(user); 
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This was tested on:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.6.0-beta.1+canary.24b19e51
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.0.2 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I'd recommend reviewing the "Creating a New Model Instance" portion of the Ember getting started guide as they cover this topic there:

> http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/creating-a-new-model/

Comment: Thanks Sarus, I was just using the starter package from the ember.js website.

DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.4.0.js:3461
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0 ember-1.4.0.js:3461
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88 ember-1.4.0.js:3461
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 ember-1.4.0.js:3461
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2 ember-1.4.0.js:3461
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 

It's the save where I get the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///G:/users. The request was redirected to 'file:///G:/users/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Comment: Out of curiousity are you running the starter package without using a web server?  Regardless, as kingpin2k mentioned you don't need the `save` call to actually have the item saved into the `store` although the new record won't be persisted.

Comment: Yeah, no web server. I was using the starter pack, I guess it was 1.4.0 on Friday and now 1.5.0, still same error. I put my Javascript up: http://jsfiddle.net/Harlequin/ZB7CQ/ The save() brings back that XMLHttpRequest error, I'm just trying to update the fixture so it has a new item in it, then refresh the view. Same with Delete, but I think if I figure out the save the delete will follow.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not hosting your project on an actual webserver as it's trying to access the local file system which Chrome does not allow.  You might want to look at something like WAMP if you're on windows to get an apache server running locally.

Comment: I gotcha. Yeah, I'm just viewing in the browser at file:///G:/EmberProject/index.html. I'm in Visual Studio I'll do a proper web :)

Comment: I'm getting a 404 now: POST http://localhost:57466/users 404 (Not Found) ...now I don't have a webservice or anything. just want to update the FIXTURE with new item and have it update. Am I not on the right path?

Comment: When you say update the FIXTURE do you mean update and persist?  Or do you just mean update the store for the browser session?  I don't think you can persist changes to the store with FIXTURES.  You would need some type of local storage adapter to do that.  Do you think you can create a fiddle to replicate your issue?  You can use this fiddle as your base: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/790/